# Properly Using the Count

Tags: mysql

I just want to count all the sub-comments as well as count all the likes from all the images that belong to a gallery.

```
SELECT Count(Message.id) AS subCount, 
       Count(likes.id), 
       Image.id, 
       Image.date_created, 
       Image.likes, 
       Image.path 
FROM   images AS Image 
       LEFT JOIN messages AS Message 
              ON ( Message.object_id = Image.id 
                   AND Message.msg_type = 16 ) 
       LEFT JOIN likes AS Likes 
              ON ( likes.object_id = Image.id 
                   AND likes.object_type = 3 ) 
WHERE  Image.gallery_id = 31
```

When i use count, it only returns 1 row. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You need a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT Count(Message.id) AS subCount, 
       Count(likes.id), 
       Image.id, 
       Image.date_created, 
       Image.likes, 
       Image.path 
FROM   images AS Image 
       LEFT JOIN messages AS Message 
              ON ( Message.object_id = Image.id 
                   AND Message.msg_type = 16 ) 
       LEFT JOIN likes AS Likes 
              ON ( likes.object_id = Image.id 
                   AND likes.object_type = 3 ) 
WHERE  Image.gallery_id = 31 
GROUP  BY Image.id, 
          Image.date_created, 
          Image.likes, 
          Image.path
```

Comment: *Sigh*. I want to create a MySQL fork which generates an admonishing error message every time an aggregate is used without a GROUP BY and the has other cols in SELECT, or ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is disabled

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY ` should be enabled by default.

Comment: Thanks. I knew that. Brain Fart.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO Imagine if they suddenly started enabling it by default - how many new _this used to work !!!!! :(_ questions we would see.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I'm scared when `mysql_` will be turned off.